# Are discrete fibrations of monoids equivalent to monoid actions?

Tags: category-theory

For any group $G$, its category of actions on sets $G-Set$ with morphisms being equivariant functions between sets. This is equivalently $Set^{BG}$ where $BG$ is its avatar as a groupoid with a single object.

An arbitrary bundle of categories $F:E\rightarrow X$ lifts morphisms if for any $f\in X$ there is $f'\in E$ such that $Ff'=f$, then when it has unique lifts to the each object in the fibre over the domain of $f$ its called a discrete opfibration.

Given such a bundle, a copreheaf can be constructed $F':X\rightarrow Set$, by setting $F'x:=F_x$ - the fibre of $F$ at $x\in X$; and for a morphism $(f:x\rightarrow y )\in X$ by setting $F'f:F_x\rightarrow F_y$ to the set function which maps the fibre of $F$ over $x$ to that of $y$ by the unique lifting property of the discrete opfibration.

For an arbitrary functor $F':X\rightarrow Set$, the category of elements construction constructs a discrete opfibration. In fact the two constructions are inverse to another, and are functorial.

But in fact any discrete opfibration over a group must be a groupoid by unique path-lifting: let $g':x\rightarrow y$ be over $g$ and $(g^{-1})':y \rightarrow x$ over $g^{-1}$, then $g'.(g^{-1})'$ is over $g.g^{-1}=e$ and by uniqueness of path-lifting this must be $1_x$.

Group actions can also be considered as action groupoids $X//G$. They are equipped with a functor to $BG$, that is faithful, and actually a discrete fibration since the fibre over the sole object in $BG$ can be identified with $X$, and given $x \in X$ and $g \in BG$ we have a unique morphism $g' \in X//G$ over $g$ which maps $x\rightarrow gx$.

Writing $Set//G$ for the category of action groupoids of $G$ equipped with a discrete fibration to $BG$, and writing $(Gpd/BG)'$ for the slice category of groupoids over $BG$ with objects as discrete opfibrations, we have the string of equivalences:

$G-Set\backsimeq Set^{BG} \backsimeq DFib^{op}(BG) \backsimeq (Gpd/BG)' \backsimeq Set//G$.

Similarly for $M$ a monoid, we can construct action monoids, and identify another string of equivalences:

$M-Set\backsimeq Set^{BM} \backsimeq DFib^{op}(BM) \backsimeq (Cat/BM)' \backsimeq Set//M$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your claim is still incorrect. $\mathbf{Grpd}_{/ G}$, as you describe it, is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^G$, not even for the trivial group $G$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: why not? If $F:\Bbb A\to 1$ is faithful, $\Bbb A$ must be equivalent to disjoint union of trivial grupoids, i.e. a set. Generally, for an action of $G$ on set $S$, let $Ob\Bbb A:= S$ and $Mor\Bbb A:=\{(a,g,b)\,\mid\,a,b\in S,\ ga=b\}$. Then $(a,g,b)\mapsto g$ is faithful. For the other direction, let $\Bbb A_0\le\Bbb A$ be a skeleton of $\Bbb A$ and $S:=Mor\Bbb A_0$ with $g\alpha:=\alpha$ if ${F|_{\hom(a,a)}}^{-1}(g)=\emptyset$ where $a={\rm dom}\,\alpha={\rm cod}\,\alpha$, and if $F(\gamma)=g$ with $\gamma:a\to a$ then $g\alpha:=\gamma\circ\alpha$.

Comment: @Berci No. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be a "codiscrete" groupoid (= has exactly one (iso)morphism between any two objects). Then $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{1}$ is faithful.

Comment: @Lin: If instead of faithful functors from a groupoid to $BG$, we had discrete opfibration - would that make the equivalence?

Comment: @ZhenLin: yes, $\Bbb A\to 1$ is faithful, but $\Bbb A$ here is equivalent to $1$. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Berci There is no notion of "equivalence" in $\mathbf{Set}$. So obviously the two categories are not equivalent.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why would we need that? The codiscrete grupoid $\Bbb A$ is equivalent to the trivial grupoid $1$ (as categories), and the construction I gave considers the morphisms of the **skeleton** of the input grupoid, which is in this case a one element set, as it should be. I still can't see where the problem is.

Comment: $\mathbb{A}$ is equivalent to but not _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb{1}$. I am refuting the claim that the category of groupoids equipped with a faithful functor to $\mathbb{1}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following result is well-known:

> **Theorem.** For any small category $\mathcal{C}$, the category of small discrete opfibrations over $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the functor category $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$.

The other equivalences appearing in your claim are essentially by definition.